Solana sdk instruction is not matching my program's instruction
I am facing an issue when using solana-sdk to call a function on my Solana program.
I have the following Program, made using Anchor:
#[program]
pub mod myprogram {
    // does not write on the SomeAccount account
    pub fn do_smth(
        ctx: Context<DoSmth>,
        data: Vec<u8>,
        signatures: Vec<Vec<u8>>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
    ....
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DoSmth<'info> {
    // #[account(mut)]
    pub some_accounts: Account<'info, SomeAccounts>,
}

#[account]
pub struct SomeAccounts{
    pub some_accounts: Vec<Vec<u8>>, // 4 + (64 bytes per public key * 20 public keys) = 1284 bytes
}

I can successfully call my "initialize" function that set the SomeAccounts account.
Then, in another Rust crate, I'm doing this in order to build the payload:
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
struct DoSmth{
    data: Vec<u8>,
    signatures: Vec<Vec<u8>>,
}

fn build_payload(
    data: Vec<u8>,
    some_other_accounts: Vec<Pubkey>,
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    signatures: Vec<Signature>,
    signer: &Pubkey,
) -> Result<Instruction> {

    let some_accounts_pubkey: [u8; 32] = bs58::decode(SOME_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS)
        .into_vec()?
        .try_into()
        .expect("44 caracters long base58 string should be 32 bytes long.");

    let some_accounts_account: AccountMeta = AccountMeta {
        pubkey: Pubkey::from(some_accounts_pubkey),
        is_signer: false,
        is_writable: false,
    };

    let mut data = vec![0, inner_data.len() as u8];
    data.extend_from_slice(&inner_data);
    data.push(signatures.len() as u8);
    for sig in signatures {
        data.extend_from_slice(&sig);
    }

    let do_smth = DoSmth {
        data,
        signatures: signatures.map(|s| s.to_bytes()).collect()
    };
    let instruction = Instruction::new_with_borsh(*program_id, &data, vec![some_other_accounts, AccountMeta::new(*signer, true)]);
    Ok(instruction)

    // Also, I tried this:

    // let mut i_data = vec![0, data.len() as u8];
    // i_data.extend_from_slice(&data);
    // i_data.push(signatures.len() as u8);
    // for sig in signatures {
    //     i_data.extend_from_slice(&sig);
    // }
    // let instruction = Instruction {
    //    program_id: *program_id,
    //    accounts: vec![some_other_accounts, AccountMeta::new(*signer, true)],
    //    i_data
    // };
    // Ok(instruction)
}

Then, I sign and execute the payload this way:
let mut transaction = Transaction::new_with_payer(&[payload], Some(&keypair.pubkey()));
let block_hash = rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash().await.unwrap();
transaction.try_sign(&[&keypair], block_hash).unwrap();
let signature = rpc_client.send_and_confirm_transaction_with_spinner(&transaction).await.unwrap();

Now, when executing this, I encounter the following error:
1: Program ... invoke [1]
2: Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error code: InstructionFallbackNotFound. Error Number; 101. Error Message: Fallback functions are not supported.

From what I've read, it mean the instruction didn't match my do_smth, so it tried to find a fallback function that I did not do. I don't understand what I am missing for my payload to match the right instruction. I verified that the public keys are valid, I verified that my signer account is funded, so i believe the issue lies in my code that uses solana_sdk, but I cannot find the actual issue

I guess you are missing the 8byte instruction discriminator:
Anchor matches these against the available functions. If it does not find any it will end up here:
    // fallback instruction handler as workaround to anchor instruction discriminator check
    pub fn fallback<'info>(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &'info [AccountInfo<'info>],
        data: &[u8],
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let instruction = TransferHookInstruction::unpack(data)?;

        // match instruction discriminator
        match instruction {
// Here could be some of your functions for example
            TransferHookInstruction::Execute { amount } => {
                
            }
            _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData.into()),
        }
    }

So you can try this to figure out whats happening.
Something like this might help to add the correct data:
pub fn get_function_hash(namespace: &str, name: &str) -> [u8; 8] {
    let preimage = format!("{}:{}", namespace, name);
    let mut sighash = [0u8; 8];
    sighash.copy_from_slice(
        &anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(preimage.as_bytes()).to_bytes()
            [..8],
    );
    sighash
}

See also here:
Anchor Instruction Discriminators
